# Want to scrape data from URL that appears after scrolling down the page using python code?

Tags: python

Need to scrape the name of college and addresses from a site : https://www.collegenp.com/2-science-colleges/ , but the problem is that i am only getting the data of first 11 college present in the list and not getting data of others.My code is :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep

driver=webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/acer/Downloads/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.collegenp.com/2-science-colleges/')

driver.refresh()
sleep(20)

page=requests.get("https://www.collegenp.com/2-science-colleges/")

college = []
location=[]

soup= BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

for a in soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'media'}):
  name=a.find('h3',attrs={'class':'college-name'})
  college.append(name.text)
  loc=a.find('span',attrs={'class':'college-address'})
  location.append(loc.text)

df=pd.DataFrame({'College name':college,'Locations':location})
df.to_csv('hell.csv',index=False,encoding='utf-8')
```

Any guidance to scrape all the data?

Comment: These are loaded dynamically with `JavaScript`, so you'd have to keep on scrolling.

Comment: [EDIT] this comment mentions a solution that can work without selenium. If you observe what happens behind the scenes in the chrome network panel (Option + ⌘ + J (on macOS), or Shift + CTRL + J (on Windows/Linux) - then select "network") you can see that when scrolling down a POST request is made to https://www.collegenp.com/2-science-colleges/ with the header `x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest` and payload `state=on&action=filter&count=10`. You can replicate what the page does, requesting entries 10 at a time increasing the value of `count` in the request payload.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is just to execute a javascript command through python. For Example:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight-200);")
```